# Numbers that can be represented by 32 bits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A   typical computer 'word' is  either 32 or 64 bits long. For each of the following    encoding,   determine   the range   of  numbers (in base 10) that can be represented with   (i) 32  bits    and with    (ii)    64  bits:

(a) Binary encoding (base 2)

I'm not really sure what the question is asking for. But for (a) my steps were:
If 2 bits can be represented in $2^2$ ways, then 32 bits/64 bits can be represented in $2^n$ ways with $n$ = 32 or 64. Is this the right process?

EDIT:
How would I figure this out for 8-bit ASCII using even parity? Not sure where to start for this.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: You are correct that the potential *number of numbers* is $2^n$. However, depending on the encoding type, the *range* of numbers may change.  If the encoding was for natural numbers only, then it could be any number from $0$ to $2^{n}-1$.  However, for integers, it is common for the first bit to denote positive or negative, and so the range is from $-2^{n-1}+1$ to $2^{n-1}-1$.  Notice that for the common encoding for integers that there is both a positive and a negative zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 bits: $2^3 = 8$
max number: $111_2$ i.e $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 = 7$

4 bits: $2^4 = 16$
max number: $1111_2$ i.e $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 = 15$

This of course also holds for 32 and 64 bit,